# Geofences are not triggering well

Tags: android, location, geofencing, android-geofence, geofence

I have designed an android app. In this app, few geofences are defined and notifications are expected while entering/exiting them. When the app is installed it works fine at first and then after some time geofences are not triggering well in samsung. Geofences are triggering randemly. Can any one help me to reduce the randomness of triggering geofences.
Note : I used google docs provided code only(link : https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing)

help me to fix this issue.

I added geofences in my app and added a pending intent and broadcast receiver to it to monitor the geofences.

I am expecting to reduce the randomness of triggering geofences.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about how it's failing?  Are you near the geofence boundary (say less than a half mile)?  Because it's totally normal for GPS to have an occasional bad read that's really off, especially in mountains or cities.  Walking around the block with a GPS tracker in Manhattan it's frequently off by a block.  The solution to that is debouncing-  wait several more samples and ensure that it wasn't a false reading.

Comment: Yes, I am near the geofence boundary and the geofence radius is 50 meters only and also I am using this app in city. The geofence is triggering fine when the app was first installed and when in the long run the geofences are not working well, especially after 1 hour without switching off the geofences are not triggered. I used the app many times but the same randomness of triggering the geofences was happened.